# Deleted a user with administrator rights. Now all the data/content/images are lost. how to recover them back

Tags: posts, customization, menus, users

I have Deleted a user with administrator rights. Now all the data/content/images are lost. how to recover the lost content and images back

Comment: How did you delete the user? Through WordPress admin?

Comment: You probably need to restore a backup. If you deleted them through admin, you had a choice to either reassign authorship to another user (which would have kept the content) or not (which seems to be the boat you're in). You'll need a file and database backup, which are often available from your host but if not, and you're quick, you might be able to recover some of it from Google's cache or the Internet Archive.

Answer (score 1):

Using WordPress methods this is not possible. If you created a backup yourself, restore that.

If you haven't, contact your host. They usually backup a customer's site and restore it (though this may cost a fee).